# How to pass a variable from GitHub action to Docker container?

Tags: docker, github-actions

When I push a commit with a tag, a docker container is automatically built by the `docker/build-push-action@v1` GitHub Actions. The tag indicates the version number, which I want to show in the application.

Here is my workflow:

```yaml
- name: Push to Docker Hub - develop
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
  with:
    repository: my_repo/my_image
    path: frontend/   
    username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
    tags: develop 
    args: SOFTWARE_VERSION=${{ steps.vars.outputs.tag }}
```

At that moment the variable `SOFTWARE_VERSION` should be available in the Dockerfile, is that right?

In my Dockerfile I set:

```
ARG SOFTWARE_VERSION
ENV SOFTWARE_VERSION ${SOFTWARE_VERSION}
```

Inside the container, the variable has an empty value. How to do it properly?

I don't know if it matters, but I run the container using `docker-compose`.

Comment: Where is the `args` key coming from? Why are you using `@v1` and not the latest `@v3`? Also, I see that there is this [`build_args`](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/tree/v1#build_args) with `@v1` and [`build-args`](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#inputs) with `@v3`. You might want to choose accordingly.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!
Btw, when I use @v3 I get the build error "dockerfile not found".  Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe, it looks for somewhere else for the `Dockerfile`. You might want to adjust the `path` accordingly.

Comment: Looks like you need to configure `context`. See https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/tree/v3#inputs and https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/tree/v3#git-context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `args` to pass the arguments.

However, the `@v1` of https://github.com/docker/build-push-action offers [build_args](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/tree/v1#build_args) and `@v3`  [build-args](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/tree/v3#inputs).

You should choose accordingly for the version that you need to use. IMO, you should go for the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Settings->Secrets and Variables

Add two Secrets

`DOCKERHUB_USERNAME` your username on Dockerhub
`DOCKERHUB_TOKEN` this is the token,you can get it from DockerHub

You must add this to precede Build and Push

```
 — name: Login to DockerHub
   if: GitHub.event_name != 'pull_request'
   uses: docker/login-action@v1
   with:
     username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
     password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I know how to add the username and token. I want to pass the version number in env.