# Call environment variable from GitHub Inputs in PowerShell script for GitHub Action that runs PS1 script using Docker

Tags: docker, powershell, github, input, github-actions

I have made a GitHub action that has an input for an URL and a path:

```yaml
inputs:
  url:  # id of input
    description: 'URL to download file from'
    required: true
  path:
    description: 'Path to store output file'
    required: false
    default: '/'
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
  args:
    - ${{ inputs.url }}
    - ${{ inputs.path }}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

LABEL "com.github.actions.name"="Download File Action"
LABEL "com.github.actions.description"="GitHub Action to download files from certain URL"

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install wget -y \
    && wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y powershell

ADD entrypoint.ps1 /entrypoint.ps1
ENTRYPOINT ["pwsh", "/entrypoint.ps1"]
```

But, how can I call the environment variable set by the GitHub Inputs in this PS1 script? (below)

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '$env:INPUT_URL' -OutFile '$env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE\$env:INPUT_PATH'
```

- I tried some different types of calling the variable, but I can't seem to find how to do it...

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75257881/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-github-action-to-docker-container

Comment: Also, according to the **Dockerfile support for GitHub Actions**' section on [WORKDIR](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/dockerfile-support-for-github-actions#workdir), "GitHub sets the working directory path in the `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` environment variable. It's recommended to not use the `WORKDIR` instruction in your Dockerfile. Before the action executes, GitHub will mount the `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` directory on top of anything that was at that location in the Docker image and set `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` as the working directory."

Comment: Ok, but do you know how I can then use these variables in the PowerShell script? I've tried $ and $Env: but they don't seem to work...

Comment: Did you try printing the values of the input variables e.g. `echo $ENV:INPUT_URL`? You don't need to use `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` as it is already mounted.

Comment: Did I tried to set the ``GITHUB_WORKSPACE`` variable? I wanted to call it for the command, but did I try to set it?

Comment: Not `GITHUB_WORKSPACE`. This path is already mounted and it's the current `WORKDIR`. You don't have to set it. I'm referring to the `inputs`. Does `echo $ENV:INPUT_URL` or `echo $ENV:INPUT_PATH` work inside the container?

Comment: I wanted to get the value of ``GITHUB_WORKSPACE``, not setting it! I just want that the user needs to enter the path from the default ``GIHUB_WORKSPACE`` from the repo so that the person only needs to enter the path from within the repo's directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251613/discussion-between-minionguyjpro-and-azeem).

Comment: Hello, sorry that I need to ask something again, but I need to fix something in the Dockerfile which won't...
The following does give an error:
```Dockerfile
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install wget -y \
&& wget -q packages.microsoft.com/config/… \
&& dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb \
&& apt-get upgrade -y && \
&& apt-get install -y git && \
apt-get install -y powershell
```

Comment: Error is:
``dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'apt-get': No such file or directory
  The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install wget -y     && wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb     && dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb     apt-get upgrade -y &&     apt-get install -y git &&     apt-get install -y powershell' returned a non-zero code: 2``

Comment: Try: `dpkg -i ./packages-microsoft-prod.deb` or `apt-get install -y ./packages-microsoft-prod.deb`

Comment: Also, verify it the `.deb` package was downloaded and it exists by using `ls` command.